# How can we use Dagger2 with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I want use Dagger2 with kotlin. But then I use this setting for dagger2 with kotlin by the way on the internet, it occurs a problem.

```
//build.gradle
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
...
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
kapt  'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

Here a problem, I am using Lombok too. Is this the problem?

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
    ... 30 more


:app:kaptStagingDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

MenuActivity

```
abstract class MenuActivity : BaseFragmentActivity() {
    @Inject
    internal var presenter: MenuPresenter? = null

    override fun baseFragmentWithTag(): Map<String, Class<out BaseManagerFragment>> {
        val map = HashMap<String, Class<out BaseManagerFragment>>()
        for (tag in MenuScreensTag.values())
            map.put(tag.getTag(), tag.getFragmentClazz())

        return map
    }

    @JvmOverloads
    fun switchTag(screensTag: MenuScreensTag, clearCurrentStack: Boolean = false) {
        val tag = screensTag.getTag()
        switchToStackByTag(tag, clearCurrentStack)
    }

    public override fun inject(appComponent: AppComponent) {
        val component = DaggerMenuComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(appComponent)
                .menuModule(MenuModule(this))
                .build()
        component.injectFragment(this)
        component.injectPresenter(presenter!!)
    }
}
```

Here is the `MenuActivity` code. 
I just use kotlin plugin to convert java to kotlin directly. Then the error occurs.

Comment: Scroll up on the error, there should be more specific error logs if it is dagger related

Comment: Yes, there are too many error info.
It seems they are related to lombok and data binding

Answer (score 0):

Like you assumed already, *Lombok* is the problem. *Kapt* runs before *Lombok* and thus some relevant classes or at least parts of it don't exist yet. Therefore compilation fails.

In our case we replaced *Lombok* with *Kotlin* data classes in one go. Alternatively you can move all these classes to a separate module which builds before you run *Kapt* the first time. If you don't have to many classes you could also de-lombok these or implement what you need manually.

Comment: and I figure out a error :
```
/Users/jafir/Documents/Base/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/stagingDebug/com/jafir/base/ui/activity/base/MenuActivity.java:7: 错误: Dagger does not support injection into private fields
e: 

e:     private com.jafir.base.ui.presenter.MenuPresenter presenter;
````
here is my code:
```
abstract class MenuActivity : BaseFragmentActivity() {
    @Inject
    internal var presenter: MenuPresenter? = null
```
it seems the presenter is private. How can it be not private ?

Comment: @韩建飞 better add the code for `MenuActivity` to your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,
I have solved this.

make

```
@Inject
internal var presenter: MenuPresenter? = null
```

to

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: MenuPresenter? = null
```